# Error: "invalid use of incomplete type ‘RSA {aka struct rsa_st}" in OpenSSL 1.1.0

Tags: c, openssl

I have old code that was written to link against an old version of openssl. Part of this code loads a key from a PEM file, and tries to understand whether this key is a private or public key, by using the following code:

```
if( (prv->p==0 || prv->q==0) ) {
    // This is not a private key!
    throw error("No private key for decryption");
}
```

With the latest version of openssl, this (justifiably) doesn't compile:

```
crypto.cpp: In function ‘key* decrypt_header(file_t, RSA*)’:
crypto.cpp:158:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘RSA {aka struct rsa_st}’
     if( (prv->p==0 || prv->q==0) ) {
             ^~
```

I understand that direct access to the struct's private members was replaced with a function, but I am having a hard time figuring out which function that is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
crypto.cpp:158:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘RSA {aka struct rsa_st}’
     if( (prv->p==0 || prv->q==0) ) {
             ^~
```

As you are aware, OpenSSL 1.1.0 changed the visibility of a lot of struct members. You can no longer access the members directly. Instead, you have to use getter and setter functions.

Try [`RSA_get0_factors`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/RSA_get0_crt_params.html). The `get0` means the reference counts are ***not*** incremented. Do *not* `BN_free` them.

```
void RSA_get0_factors(const RSA *r, const BIGNUM **p, const BIGNUM **q);
```

---

If the code supports multiple versions of OpenSSL, then you will need a guard because `RSA_get0_factors` is for OpenSSL 1.1.0 and above. Maybe something like the following. Also see [`OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER.html).

```
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>

#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x10100000L

    /* OpenSSL 1.0.2 and below (old code) */

#else

    /* OpenSSL 1.1.0 and above (new code) */

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea where I was supposed to find this without re-learning openssl?

Comment: @ShacharShemesh - I think you have to suffer it... The [1.1.0 Change Log](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html) stated a bunch of structures were made private. Because a replacement was needed, I checked the online [OpenSSL man pages](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manpages.html) for the RSA functions looking for the one that fetched `p` and/or `q`. I started at [OpenSSL man pages](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manpages.html), drilled into 1.1.0, drilled into Crypto, and then searched for ***`RSA_`***. Over time the OpenSSL wiki will probably accumulate the new code in its examples.

Comment: The `get0` and `get1` thing has been around for a while. You usually learn that one early (and the hard way) when you start chasing problems under Valgrind. You will wonder why you had a leak when you called a `get1` function, or you will segfault with a double free by free'ing something from a `get0` function. I point out the `get0` and `get1` to save others the trouble. Someone will stumble upon this post and have an "oh shit" moment...

Comment: A FOSS program of mine that I have last update in 2010 has been removed from Debian because it would not work with the latest version of openssl. Frankly, I'm trying to get it to work and that's it. If/when I get around to updating it, it will be a fairly major update, but not now.

Comment: What part of "it's an old project" did you not understand? :-) https://sourceforge.net/projects/rsyncrypto/
I've already updated the Linux sources. Now working on bringing my Windows VM up to date so I can create a new release. Haven't turned it on in 2 years.

Comment: Sent you an email. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

After 1.1.1 OpenSSL Supports getter what return each parameter like this.

```
const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_n(const RSA *d);
const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_e(const RSA *d);
const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_d(const RSA *d);
const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_p(const RSA *d);
const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_q(const RSA *d);
const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_dmp1(const RSA *r);
const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_dmq1(const RSA *r);
const BIGNUM *RSA_get0_iqmp(const RSA *r);
```

So if you don't need to considerate below version of OpenSSL less than 1.1.1 these code will make simple code. AND other structures support kind of this getter too. You can find more information of functions this. https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/

Answer (score 1):

```
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x10100005L
static void RSA_get0_key(const RSA *r, const BIGNUM **n, const BIGNUM **e, const BIGNUM **d, const BIGNUM **p, const BIGNUM **q)
{
    if(n != NULL)
        *n = r->n;

    if(e != NULL)
        *e = r->e;

    if(d != NULL)
        *d = r->d;

    if(p != NULL)
        *p = r->p;

    if(q != NULL)
        *q = r->q;
}
#endif

const BIGNUM *bn_p;
const BIGNUM *bn_q;

RSA_get0_key(key, NULL, NULL, NULL, &bn_p, &bn_q);
/*   if( (prv->p==0 || prv->q==0) ) { */
if( (prv_p==0 || prv_q==0) ) {
```