# Link error with OpenSSL compiling on Visual Studio 2010 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openssl

I am attempting to execute a program that compiles and links fine in Code::Blocks on windows, but when porting it over to Visual Studio, I am getting a link error.

[image: Errors from Visual Studio Window]

I have made sure that the include and lib folders are correctly linked in the properties configuration.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would like to help you but I can't see a damn thing on this tiny picture. I tried to enlarge it but it didn't help. I tried to change a fond but it didn't work. POST TEXT.

Comment: You apparently missed to specify the library itself.

Comment: I am sorry, the error is `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _OPENSSL_config referenced in function _main`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you explain more? I don't understand... The configuration asks for the directory and not the specific file. How do you specify the right file?

Comment: @Matthew Did you check `Input`??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You are exactly right! Thank you for your time!