# EVP_get_cipherbyname and "undefined struct/union evp_cipher_st" in OpenSSL 1.1.0

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, openssl, windows-10, header-files

I'm trying to use openssl with visual studio c project.

I compiled openssl using visual studio nmake command then installed everything to a predefined folder (C:\openssl) using:

```
nmake install
```

The folder structure is as following:

- `bin`
- `include/openssl`
- `lib`

Inside include/openssl there are .h header files.

In my Visual studio 2012, I created an empty general c++ project and included C:\openssl\include

```
[Project properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories]
```

I also added lib directory and .lib files.

But when I compile the code, I get

```
left of 'key_len' specifies undefined struct/union 'evp_cipher_st'
```

Inside my code I have these lines

```
const EVP_CIPHER *cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname("aes-256-cbc");
//some other code
return cipher->key_len;
```

Looking into ossl_typ.h file for evp_cipher_st definition, it is declared as

```
typedef struct evp_cipher_st EVP_CIPHER;
```

and there is no definition for the struct body!

Digging more into the source tree, evp_cipher_st is defined in crypto\include\internal\evp_int.h that is not included in the include folder of openssl install folder.

I also tried to include crypto\include\internal\evp_int.h out of the box but it leads to more problems.

Any idea how to fix that?

UPDATE:

Here is the complete function and my main including all the includes:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <mswsock.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <minwindef.h>
#include <malloc.h>
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef int socklen_t;
#include "wingetopt.h"
#include <Wincrypt.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include <Bcrypt.h>

#define inline __inline
#define STATUS_SUCCESS 0

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

int generate_aes_key(const unsigned char *input_key, uint16_t input_key_size,
            unsigned char *output_key, uint16_t *outputkey_size) {

        const EVP_MD *dgst = NULL;
        unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
        const EVP_CIPHER *cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname("aes-256-cbc");

        if(!cipher) {

            return -1;
        }

        dgst = EVP_get_digestbyname("sha256");

        if(!dgst) {

            fprintf(stderr, "no such digest\n");
            return -2;
        }

        if(!EVP_BytesToKey(cipher, dgst, NULL, input_key, input_key_size, 1, output_key, iv)) {

            return -3;
        }

        *outputkey_size = (uint16_t)cipher->key_len;

        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char secret[] = "MIIFBTCCAu2gAwIBAgICEAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwTjELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0Ix";

    unsigned char shared_secret[500];
    uint16_t aes_keylen = 0;

    //bunch of codes 

    if(generate_aes_key((unsigned char *)secret, strlen(secret), shared_secret, &aes_keylen) < 0) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Could not get initial shared secret\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //other codes
}
```

Openssl version is:

> OpenSSL_1_1_0-pre6-1266-g487d3a726

Above version is the latest tag name from git, I think its the most fresh one till now. The latest commit version and date is as following:

> 487d3a726a1970e84853434561d88cb4ac212d15
>
> Author: EasySec  Date:   Tue Jan 17 17:21:55 2017 +0100

And finally here is the Visual Studio 2012 compile output:

```
Build started 1/28/2017 8:23:02 PM.
 1>Project "C:\CODE\mycode.vcxproj" on node 2 (Build target(s)).
 1>ClCompile:
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /I"c:\openssl\include" /ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D _MBCS /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc110.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:prompt src\main.c ... 

     wingetopt.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     crypto.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
 1>c:\CODE\src\crypto.c(517): error C2037: left of 'key_len' specifies undefined struct/union 'evp_cipher_st'
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     client.c
 1>c:\openssl\include\openssl\lhash.h(198): warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
     Generating Code...
 1>Done Building Project "C:\CODE\mycode.vcxproj" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:08.55
```

Comment: You should include [`evp.h`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/evp.h). Are you doing that? Otherwise, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Effectively, we need to see a complete `main` with the functions you are calling. We may need to see the compile command, so you should provide it, too. Finally, state the version of OpenSSL you are using.

Comment: I included evp.h too, but it did not do anything. Ok I'll update the question with additional information, thanks

Comment: This looks OK from your compile command: `I"c:\openssl\include"`. There is no `evp.h` in your program. You should include `<openssl/evp.h>`.

Comment: @jww It sounds for the newer versions of openssl there is no need to include evp.h file for the evp_cipher_st structure. Its turned into opaque type. Anyway thanks for the Follow up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the **key length** using:

```
*outputkey_size = EVP_CIPHER_key_length(cipher);
```

Putting in the end of your code the next lines:

```
printf("Key-size: %d\n", aes_keylen);
printf("Key: "); for (int i = 0; i<aes_keylen; ++i) { printf("%02x", shared_secret[i]); } printf("\n");
```

It prints the correct output, which is next:

```
Key-size: 32
Key: 51ae3ac4721439302cc5f90313f440bd9ca714c9a80b2213d034c87c00a700a0
```

I'm not sure if **key_len** was available on previous versions but in the [openssl-1.10 release notes](https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.1.0-notes.html) you can read:

> - *Most* libcrypto and libssl public structures were made opaque, including: BIGNUM and associated types, EC_KEY and EC_KEY_METHOD, DH
>     and DH_METHOD, DSA and DSA_METHOD, RSA and RSA_METHOD, BIO and
>     BIO_METHOD, EVP_MD_CTX, EVP_MD, EVP_CIPHER_CTX, EVP_CIPHER, EVP_PKEY
>     and associated types, HMAC_CTX, X509, X509_CRL, X509_OBJECT,
>     X509_STORE_CTX, X509_STORE, X509_LOOKUP, X509_LOOKUP_METHOD
> - libssl internal structures made opaque

which means that the applications are no longer allowed to look inside the variables of the structures. This is the reason that _key_len (and others) shows undefined.

Comment: Thank you @jgorosdev the solution works well. It sounds this struct has became an opaque type for newer openssl versions

Comment: @pendrive - It looks like you ran into [Error: “invalid use of incomplete type ‘RSA {aka struct rsa_st}” in OpenSSL 1.1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40549318) and [Visual Studio and error C2027: use of undefined type 'rsa_st'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41348281)